# QR code won't launch Google+ app on Android device

Tags: android, iphone, qr-code

I am trying to get a QR code to launch the Google+ app on the iPhone and android mobile devices.

I have tried replacing **http://** with **mgc://** and **gplus://** to get this going, and shortened the url using [Tiny URL](http://tinyurl.com/create.php) then generated the [QR code](http://www.qrstuff.com/).

I have managed to get the app to launch on the iPhone, but can't get it to launch on android devices.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried another lib for example([WebQR](http://webqr.com/)) ? 
It works for all kind of browsers and also for Android.
It allows you for create and read QR via webcam or uploading images.

Comment: Thanks for this, however it still won't open the Google+ app on my android phone. It comes up with the following message even though I have the Google+ app installed on my android phone: "Sorry we cannot open this link. There are no apps installed that can handle it".